# Flexbox inside Flexbox (Slider)

Tags: html, css, flexbox, slider, flexslider

I want to create a horizontal Slider with Sections.

```
<div class="slider">
  <div class="section">
    <div class="card">Section 1 Card 1</div>
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="section">
    <div class="card">Section 2 Card 1</div>
    ...
  </div>
  ...
</div>
```

My idea:
slider is a container with the section and i will transform the content on the x axis everytime I navigate through it. 
My Problem:
I tried with flexbox, but the sections and cards are overlapping and I don't know why.

Maybe you can help me?

Codepen:
https://codepen.io/thor-ben/pen/XWJgeEo

Comment: Can you provide an image with the desired result?

Comment: Hey, sorry for the late response!

It should be a simple slider, but with one more level (the section) level.
The Problem is, i want the card width (percentage) depending on the slider width

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if im understanding you correctly, but if you want each card of each section having a width of 100vw, so each card fit in the whole screen lenght, you could use this css:

```
.slider {
  position: absolute;
  width: auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  justify-content:space-between;
  overflow: scroll;
  /*overflow: hidden;*/
}

.section {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.card {
  width: 100vw;
  height:200px;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0, .2);
}
```

but, if you prefer each section having 4 cards of equal widht that fits in the whole screen all together **(EDIT: "and using percentages in the sections and cards")**, you can set

```
.slider {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  overflow: scroll;
  /*overflow: hidden;*/
}
    .section {
  width: 100%;
  min-width:100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.card {
  width: calc(100%/4);
  min-height: 200px;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0, .2);
}
```

instead of `100vw`;

Also, if you want to hide the scrollbar, becuse you are planning to move between cards or sections by translating the content over the X axis using javascript, you could set:

```
body{
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

I hope it was helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, sorry for the late response!

The Problem is, i don't want vw for the cards, i want percentage of the 100vw (because of the scrollbar on the y-axis).

the Slider should have a given width (100vw in this case, but maybe 400px) and the cards should take percentage(10/12) of that 400px the slider has.

Comment: sorry this does not fix my problem :x

i want cards with a width of percentage(10/12) (12 column grid layout) and a margin left of percentage(.5/12) so you can see a part of the next card on the screen. The problem is that i want one more level, the section and this forces the cards to be not 10/12 columns of the grid